# Matlab: jsconencode with function handles

Tags: matlab

Consider the following cell array in matlab

```
    mycell = {@sin,@cos}
```

It has two elements each of them is a function handle.
Now when I call

```
    jsonencode(mycell)
```

I get the error "Unable to encode objects of class function_handle as JSON-formatted text".
Is there a way to get around this error by forcing Matlab to use the output of func2str() of the function handle?

Comment: What do you expect as result?... `["sin", "cos"]`?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the function handles before you encode the cell:

```
function c = prepare_cell( c ) 
    % replace function handles
    idx = cellfun(@(x) isa(x, 'function_handle'), c);
    for ii = find(idx)
        c{ii} = func2str(c{ii});
    end
    % repeat for cells in cells
    idx = cellfun(@(x) iscell(x), c);
    for ii = find(idx)
        c{ii} = prepare_cell(c{ii});
    end
end
```

Usage:

```
>> c = {@sin, @cos, 1, 2, {@sin, @cos, 1, 2}};
>> jsonencode(prepare_cell(c))

ans =

    '["sin","cos",1,2,["sin","cos",1,2]]'
```